# What proportion of salt in water would make it not dehydrate nor hydrate someone?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology

Drinking sea water can be deadly as it contains too much salt, basically de-hydrating the body. Normal tap water contains little salt and is good for re-hydration. My question: How much salt needs to be dissolved in water such that it does not hydrate nor de-hydrate? For instance, would a physiologic saline solution (9 grams of salt per liter of water) meet this criterion?

Comment: You are looking for physiological saline which is isotonic to most tissues. It is about 0.9% w/v, which equates to ~9g NaCl per liter water.

Comment: @kmm I thought isotonic solutions were often used in sports for rehydration?

Comment: There is no saline solution which will not either hydrate or dehydrate someone. Pure water hydrates, sea water dehydrates, and everything in between does one ot the other. You need to clarify your thinking on what constitutes "hydration".

Comment: @anongoodnurse Why do you say that? There are solutions that can be isosmotic with the cytoplasm. I agree that the cytoplasm can have small variations in osmolarity and you may not find a mathematically exact universal isotonic solution. Why do you think 0.9% saline won't be grossly isosmotic?

Comment: @AliceD The sports drinks are mostly for restoring electrolytes.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I disagree with your comment. Why would there be only two extremes and no middle ground?

Comment: @Nit - "everything in between does one ot the other." That's the middle ground. If you're not dehydrated, you cannot "hydrate" with a perfect imaginary solution. The body will remove the unnecessary salts of anything added. There is no magic solution.

Comment: @WYSIWYG - see above. The body doesn't keep solutes it doesn't need. There are isotonic solutions, but if a person is normally hydrated, the solutes of the solution will be removed, in effect reducing it to something close to water. There is no one answer for this question. It depends entirely on the state of "hydration".

Comment: @anongoodnurse That still makes no sense. What about solutions that are perfectly balanced between the body-needs-solutes and body-doesn't-need-solutes?

Comment: @anongoodnurse I still did not get it. I am talking in the sense of cells and tissues, not a human body. Isosmotic is not enough for excitable cells like neurons, for which the ions also have to be balanced; so lets assume PBS instead of normal saline.

Comment: @WYSIWYG - I didn't realize you were speaking about a cell; of course there are isotonic solutions. But the OP is asking about a human body (I presume), and my answer is unchanged for that question.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Perhaps you would want to write your point up as an answer (with references etc) on the [other](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35727/at-what-saltiness-will-water-simply-pass-through-us) post. The comments do not explain the situation properly and are also confusing.

Comment: @Nit Oh sorry.. there was a confusion. I thought you asked anongoodnurse to read about loops of henle etc. Sorry. However you have to work on your other question- on terminologies and w.r.t addition of your own analysis on the issue.

Comment: I am closing this question as a dupe of [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35727/at-what-saltiness-will-water-simply-pass-through-us) post since the latter has an answer.